# Finding the number of lines & characters by which an index was shifted upon string change

Tags: javascript, collaboration, codemirror, string-search

Is there some algorithm(or its JavaScript implementation) to find the amount of shift in a word's position when the string containing the word was changed?

My project is an online editor based on CodeMirror where I need to re-position the cursor when new data has been added to the code using the MobWrite collaboration service.

Therefore, to set the cursor-position to the word that the current user was editing, I think I need to calculate the amount of shift in its position & add that to the original cursor-position.

Solution:
 Now, I'm trying to implement the method used by [MobWrite](http://neil.fraser.name/writing/cursor/).

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Could you give some examples of what you are looking for? Original string, changed string, result. Otherwise Levenshtein distance is pretty much the only answer you can get and it is not clear whether that's what you want.

Comment: @WladimirPalant , With it being a collaborative editor, the data keeps changing, so I need a way to keep the position of the cursor consistent with what the current user was typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution implemented by MobWrite is quite comprehensive & can be found here: http://neil.fraser.name/writing/cursor/ .

The solution to the problem I was actually trying to solve can be found here: [Getting CodeMirror to follow a TextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499541/getting-codemirror-to-follow-a-textarea/7517764#7517764)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

On that page are other distance types. Check if they meet your need better.

Comment: @user937891: The Levenshtein algorithm allows you to both calculate the number of operations necessary to transform old text into new text and to actually get these operations. So you can find out which text parts have been inserted or removed and adjust cursor position accordingly.

Comment: You would use a variant that only include additions and deletions (longest common subsequence). Then subtract them, and that's how much you should move the cursor.